# Difference between Locking and logout?

Tags: 16.04, lock-screen, logout

I use `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`.

By presing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, I logout from my user session for a lunch break, then all the applications running are vanished and not available on my re-log-in again.

What is happening?

Answer (score 3):

**Logging out** means that all applications quit(work is not saved) and your user session ends.

**Locking**, on the other hand, simply means that you have to enter your password to 'unlock' your computer. Any applications you have running will still be there when you get back.

Usually, Ubuntu will give you both options when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>. Select lock if you wish to keep any unsaved data.